# Get access to div where attribute angular component is placed

Tags: angular, components, angular-components

I have an angular component defined like this

```
 <div [app-collapsible-column] class="col-sm-3 relatives-left-list" [direction]="'left'">
```

What I want to achieve is modify the class from inside the app-collapsible-column component code. I know I can get the references of template through `ViewChild`. However, how can I get the reference of the div on which the component is itself defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can expose [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) inside app-collapsible-column component

```
 constructor(public ele:ElementRef){
 }
```

Then inside parent component we can access div element using ViewChild something like this

```
@ViewChild(CollapsibleColumn) componentRef:CollapsibleColumn;
   
ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.componentRef.ele);
}
```